# POST data to server window.onload

Tags: javascript, post, firefox

I would like to send data to a web page through javascript. The code below works, however only with chrome. For example Firefox the code does not work. Do you know another method to send data when loading page that works on all browsers?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="FormType" method="post" action="/welcome.php">
<input type="hidden" name="var1" value="abc">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function autoClick () {
  document.forms["FormType"].submit();
   }
 window.onload = autoClick;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like it should work. Is there an error in the developer console?

Comment: The code works without error. Firefox does not pass the post data without showing any error. While chrome the data is printed on the landing page.